# Dependency Injection into Roslyn analyzers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mef, roslyn, vsix

I have a custom Roslyn analyzer which inherits from `DiagnosticAnalyzer`. It is packed in VSIX extension which contains custom `Package` class. I'd like to pass an instance of a class with the settings (`CodeAnalysisSettings` instance) from the package to my `DiagnosticAnalyzer`.

I've tried to use MEF for that purpose. I've registered an instance of my settings class in VS Package using the following code:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    base.Initialize();
    IComponentModel componentModel = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel;
    new CompositionContainer(componentModel.DefaultCatalog).ComposeExportedValue(
                new CodeAnalysisSettings(...));
}
```

Analyzer looks as follows:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class MyAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    [Import]
    public CodeAnalysisSettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Settings class:

```
[Export]
public class CodeAnalysisSettings
{
    public CodeAnalysisSettings()
    {
    }

    public bool RecursiveAnalysisEnabled { get; }
}
```

For some reason `Settings` property is not imported - its value is always null.

Please help.

Comment: Analyzers are created by the Roslyn compilation process and do not use MEF.

Comment: @SLaks but for some reason, we have to mark `CodeFixProvider` classes with `ExportCodeFixProviderAttribute` which inherits from MEF `ExportAttribute`. It means that MEF is used at least for a part of Roslyn-related classes.

Comment: Yes, but only in the Workspaces layer or above.  The core compiler does not depend on MEF; `DiagnosticAnalyzer` is not an export.  See https://blog.slaks.net/2014-04-07/exploring-roslyn-part-1-introduction/

Comment: Thanks for the article! Does it mean that it is impossible to pass any VS settings to the analyzer? I've been thinking about using `Autofac` with `ServiceLocator` for that purpose.

Comment: It's not impossible but analyzers were built to run outside of Visual Studio (eg. on a CI build server) so there's no built-in mechanism for it. For example you could always hack it in by storing the component model in some static class somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up using a service locator (CommonServiceLocator package) that consumes MEF container as a source.

Since VS infrastructure doesn't allow adding new registrations (`IComponentModel.DefaultCatalog` throws an exception which tells that this functionality is not supported anymore), I've created a new container inside `Package.Initialize()`:

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(CompositionOptions.Default, componentModel.DefaultExportProvider);
container.ComposeExportedValue<CodeAnalysisSettings>(new CodeAnalysisSettings(...));
var serviceLocator = new MefServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
```

Roslyn diagnostic consumes this dependency:

```
var settings = CodeAnalysisSettings.Default;
if (ServiceLocator.IsLocationProviderSet)
    settings = ServiceLocator.GetInstance<CodeAnalysisSettings>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft VSIX Community Toolkit has a Dependency Injection Nuget package that adds DI to your VSIX extension.  It allows you to add your own IOC container or use theirs.

[VSIX Community Toolkit Package on GitHub](https://github.com/VsixCommunity/Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit.DependencyInjection)